# Swift - Get all records from Cloudkit Public Database

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, database, cloudkit

Hi i'm trying to fetch all records from my publicDB in cloudkit, and currently there are more of 2000 records. How can I fetch them all and put them in an array?
I've tryed these two methods without success. Can you please help me?

## 1 Approach

```
    let predicate = NSPredicate(value: true)
    let query = CKQuery(recordType: "Position", predicate: predicate)
    query.sortDescriptors = [NSSortDescriptor(key: "creationDate", ascending: false)]

publicDB.perform(query, inZoneWith: nil) { (results, error) -> Void in            

        if error != nil {

            DispatchQueue.main.async(execute: {  () -> Void in
                self.delegate?.errorUpdating(error: error! as NSError)
                return
            })
        } else {
            self.positionArray.removeAll(keepingCapacity: true)

            for record in results! {

                let position = Position(record: record as CKRecord, database: self.publicDB)
                self.positionArray.append(position)

            }
        }

            DispatchQueue.main.async(execute: {  () -> Void in
               /* my elaboration with the complete result */
            })



    }
```

## 2 Approach

```
    let predicate = NSPredicate(value: true)   
    let query = CKQuery(recordType: "Position", predicate: predicate)

    query.sortDescriptors = [NSSortDescriptor(key: "creationDate", ascending: false)]

    let qop  = CKQueryOperation(query: query)

    qop.resultsLimit = 3000        
    qop.recordFetchedBlock = { (record: CKRecord) in
        let position = Position(record: record, database: self.publicDB)
        self.positionArray.append(position)
        print(self.positionArray.count)
    }

    qop.queryCompletionBlock = { (cursor: CKQueryOperation.Cursor?, error: Error?) in
        DispatchQueue.main.async(execute: {  () -> Void in
        if let cursor = cursor {

            print("entro")
            let newOperation = CKQueryOperation(cursor: cursor)

            newOperation.recordFetchedBlock = qop.recordFetchedBlock
            newOperation.queryCompletionBlock = qop.queryCompletionBlock
            self.publicDB.add(newOperation)
        }

        else if let error = error {
            print("Error:", error)
        }
            // No error and no cursor means the operation was successful
        else {
            print("Finished with records:", self.positionArray)
            if(!all){
                // my elaboration
            }
            else{
                // my elaboration
            }
        }
        })
    }

    self.publicDB.add(qop)
```

With the first approach I can fetch at most 100 records.
With the second approach I can fetch at most 400 records.
But i need to fill my array with the all over 2000 records, how can achieve the result?

Answer (score 1):

Plese, Try this one!

var Whistle = [CKRecord] ()

```
func loadWhistles(completionHandler: (() -> Void)?) {
    let pred = NSPredicate(value: true)
    let sort = NSSortDescriptor(key: nomeDaTabela, ascending: ordemDaTabela)
    let query = CKQuery(recordType: "Cliente", predicate: pred)
    query.sortDescriptors = [sort]        

    let operation = CKQueryOperation(query: query)
    operation.desiredKeys = ["Name"]
    operation.resultsLimit = 2000

    var newWhistles = Whistle

    operation.recordFetchedBlock = { record in
        newWhistles.append(record)

    }


    operation.queryCompletionBlock = { [unowned self] (cursor, error) in
        DispatchQueue.main.async {
            if error == nil {
                //ViewController.isDirty = false
                self.clienteRecords = newWhistles
                self.clientesTableView.reloadData()
            } else {
                let ac = UIAlertController(title: "Fetch failed", message: "There was a problem fetching the list of whistles; please try again: \(error!.localizedDescription)", preferredStyle: .alert)
                ac.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "OK", style: .default))
                self.present(ac, animated: true)
            }
        }
    }


    PublicDatabase.add(operation)
    completionHandler?()

}
```

Answer (score 0):

There is indeed a limit of 400 records per fetch operation, so you need to check `CKQueryCursor` value returned by *query completion block*, and if it is not `nil` start another operation with it `CKQueryOperation(cursor: cursor)`.

So in principle your 2nd approach is correct. My guess is that your problem occurs due to threading issue, try removing `DispatchQueue.main.async(execute: {  () -> Void in`.

P.S. Check out how it is done in `RxCloudKit` (which handles big fetches automatically), it definitely works for fetching 1000+ records - [RecordFetcher.queryCompletionBlock(cursor: CKQueryCursor?, error: Error?)](https://github.com/maxvol/RxCloudKit/blob/master/RxCloudKit/RecordFetcher.swift)